# Using case statements to retrieve information from a web page using Perl

Tags: perl

I am currently trying to extract and break up information for a Web page that contains temperature readings. I am a complete beginner when it comes to Perl and I'm having some trouble. The page I'm trying to extract information from is: http://temptrax.itworks.com/temp.
So far I was able to figure out how to get the page and break up the four temperature readings into four lines using split. Here is what I was able to come up with so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use v5.10.1;

my $content = get('http://temptrax.itworks.com/temp');
my @split = split ('Probe',$content);

foreach my $split(@split){
$split =~ s/'Probe''|'/ /g;

print $split . "\n";

}
```

The next step that I'm having trouble with is separating the four temperature reading using case statements. I don't quite understand how to do them. I want to be able to get a readings for each each probe separately when giving a specific number 1-4. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by `case` statements?

Comment: I might have worded the question in the wrong way. Sorry. What I am looking to do is something like this: switch ($temp) {
    case "1"  { print "temperature for probe 1"      }

Comment: Why not just parse the data into a hash and use that? seems a lot simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By parsing directly into a hash, we can simply iterate over the keys, or do whatever else one would want to do with the data structure. No `case` needed. BTW the `Switch` module is deprecated and really should not be used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

my $content = get('http://temptrax.itworks.com/temp');
my %probes = $content =~ /Probe\s*(\d)\|\s*(\-?[\d\.]+)/g;

foreach my $probe (sort keys %probes) {
  print "$probe => $probes{$probe}\n";
}
```

The regex can be explained (and even replaced) by this:

```
my %probes = $content =~ /
  Probe\s*      # starts with Probe
  (             # start capture
    \d            # a number (probe)
  )             # end capture
  \|\s*         # separated with a pipe symbol
  (             # start capture
    \-?           # possibly negative
    [\d\.]+       # digits or decimals (at least one)
  )             # end capture
/gx;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the in depth explanation.